# Trying to disable google form questions if user from a certain whitelisted domain accesses it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have two whitelisted domains in my organization, and I have a form that should not be fillable by any user in one of those domains.  The form automatically collects the full address of the user.  So...  anybody@domain1.com should be able to open the form, fill it out, and submit it.  everyone@domain2.com should be blocked in some way from filling and sending the form.  Remember, they're not entering an e-mail address; the address is simply auto-filled via normal GForm rules.

I'm starting to look into using Google script to do this somehow, but am unfamiliar with it - thought dropping a question here while I look would be beneficial.

Comment: I don't know of anyway to interact with the form while it's being filled out.  All we can do is wait until it is submitted and read the answers to questions.

Comment: I know there are add-ons that can manipulate a form based on selections... Answering "True" on question 1 removed questions 2 and 3, etc.  I've just not seen a solution that can read the collected e-mail domain and manipulate the form based on that.